# I can't get createdAt value form Parse(Back4App) by using PHP

Tags: parse-platform, fetch, back4app

Despite I use $object->getCreatedAt() function I cant fetch the createdAt column's values. Need help. Thanks in advance for all.

```
$tableFetch = new Database(); // This is my custom class structure
$subscriptions = $tableFetch->tableFetch("Subscribe");

for ($i = 0; $i < count($subscriptions); $i++) { 
     $object = $subscriptions[$i];
     $createdAt = $object->getCreatedAt();
}
```

Edit: I can get the information of array but cant slice it with keys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

After creating DateTime Object need to specify format as below.

```
$createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```